# "Semi-shielded" inductor likely to pass EMC?

Tags: inductor, emc, switching-regulator

I'm designing a board with a 2.1 MHz [LMR16006Y](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lmr16006y-q1) switching regulator. The equation in the datasheet and WEBENCH suggest a relatively large 56 μH inductor. The inductor must come from LCSC, where there is a limited selection of inductors with published SRF specifications.

One option is to use a "semi-shielded" inductor. Has anyone used these? Can anyone tell me if the board is likely to pass EMC (e.g. CISPR32) with one of these on the output?

The layout will be almost identical to the 2-layer evaluation board, with a continuous 1 oz ground plane.

I'm also planning to add an additional Pi filter on the input using the same 56 μH inductor and an additional 33 μF cap (shown in schematic).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont think the eval kits go through EMI testing, so copying the layout doesnt guarantee anything. (I've seen some terrible eval kits out there, from reputable brands).

Comment: Are you sure pi filters / output inductors are not going to ring wildly with your proposed load?  Webbench / eval kits are just a starting place; still have to do the real work of simulating, tweaking, and testing.  Of more consequence might be the rise-time of the switcher; ultra fast = spurious emissions into hundreds of MHz due to Fourier composition.

Comment: Wesley - good point.

Comment: Rdtsc, to be clear: I don't know what I'm doing. I cobble together various circuits and things tend work most of the time... For the Pi filter I was planning to add a bit of series resistance. Whether the filter will cause problems or is necessary, I don't know. Regarding the output filter, I know the inductor determines the ripple current, and that the RC is required to filter the switching frequency, but that's about all. It seems odd that Webench creates a filter with a Q of 50, but what do I know? Not knowing any better, I would be inclined to increase the output cap, or add a snubber.

Comment: The switching regulator by itself is just a part of the system. Without knowing how it's used, there's little one can suggest. Switchers by themselves don't necessarily cause trouble - it's usually the system around them that lets their noise radiate out, or mix with other frequencies, etc. So, you'd need to provide quite a lot of detail about your system/product to see what it is that you actually need. An unshielded inductor will radiate somewhat, but a foot of cable that radiates instead will swamp whatever the inductor can do.

Comment: EMC is a holistic study -- you will have to provide MUCH more information to make a determination like that. An inductor, in and of itself, is a very small component in relation to the waves going through it, and unlikely to have much effect. It can also be shielded fairly easily if need be. Don't worry about it. By a huge margin, your priorities are any cables hanging off the device, and PCB layout.

Comment: I guess the concise question is "can a semi shielded inductor cause a board to fail EMC alone." I've since gathered that semi-shielded inductors are only slightly better than unshielded. The board is part of a powered speaker and there are many EMI sources, so of course there are many opportunities to fail EMC.  There is an off the shelf 48V psu operating at 65khz which is attached to the main board by about 6 inches of unshielded cable. There is a TI class D amp running at 450, 500 or 600khz. There is a bluetooth module. There is the LM16006Y regulator which feeds a 12V linear regulator.

Comment: Most EMC issues will be related to regulator and ground layouts. However, I do have extensive experience of using the various simple switcher families (ever since they were still National) with bad and good layouts both and they tend to not perform well. In several cases we've redone the layout multiple times but still face EMC problems. Then switch to a LT part with a very similar layout and swoosh: all problems are suddenly gone. So you do get what you pay for, at some extent. Also, I would not recommend semi-shielded coils, I have bad experience of those as well. Use fully shielded.

Comment: Then add non-technical arguments such as TI hate having non-existent technical support and hate having customers in general... I've not fully blacklisted TI, but I wouldn't pick any parts from them in new designs other than as the last resort.

Comment: Thanks Lundin. I will try the LMR16006 and if the EMI is too high then will maybe try and LT part.

Comment: Webench and the datasheet are conservative on allowable ripple current and ripple current can actually be up to 0.6x Iout according to a TI engineer in TI's forums. This means I can use as little as 0.27uH, and perhaps even less. It is still hard to find a part with an SRF of 5x switching freq and is capable of delivering 1.6A (a requirement for current limiting to work) LCSC has some TDK parts that fit the bill, but I am hesitant to be reliant on a single component being in stock. I may have a couple of PCBs built with just the PSU to test EMI of both the shielded and unshielded inductors

Comment: No matter which regulator you pick, go with fully shielded inductors. Quite recently I had a project where we also used a simple switcher, but it disturbed nearby RF parts too much (through radiated emissions). Then we used the same circuit but shielded inductors and it significantly improved the situation, but still not perfect. Then we threw TI in the garbage and went with LT/Analog and then all remaining problems went away too. I've had very similar experiences in the past.